# How to calculate the probability out of an array in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, probability

I have an array with 10 values. Each of these values represents a percentage to win something. For example row 1 has a chance of 50% to win something. 
What is an elegant way to implement that?

I fill the array with the values of the data source:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.power[i] = this.dataSource.data[i].power;
    }
```

The power array represents the probabilities of each person to win. Row 1: 50% Row 2: 10%,... 
What I want as output is the winning row after the calculation of the probability. So Row 1 for example has the highes probability to win --> higher chance that I will get 1 as output.

[image]

Comment: Whats your try? Have you looked into filters

Comment: No. Didn't have a look at filters, but I will look it up now.

Comment: Can you be explicit about what output you are expecting?  You are given an array of probabilities (represented as percentage points) and you want to produce... the same array of probabilities?  The array where each element is divided by 100?  The sum of the array?  The number 100?  The number 50?  The number 1?  The number 0.5?  The number 42?  It's hard to know what you are asking.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: So you want a random output where the array is treated as a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)?

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question as: given an array of probabilities, possibly not normalized (that is, they might not add to 1.0), produce a random index into the array which whose chance of being produced is proportional to the probability at that index.

This means you need a random number generator somewhere.  I will by default use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), but you can replace it with any random number generator with the same contract: a no-arg function that produces a number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
// probabilities: array of (possibly not normalized) probabilities like [4,3,2,1]
// randomGenerator: function producing a random number, uniform distribution from 0≤x<1
function randomIndex(
  probabilities: number[], 
  randomGenerator: () => number = Math.random
): number {

    // get the cumulative distribution function
    let acc: number = 0;
    const cdf = probabilities
        .map(v => acc += v) // running total [4,7,9,10]
        .map(v => v / acc); // normalize to max 1 [0.4,0.7,0.9,1]

    // pick a random number between 0 and 1
    const randomNumber = randomGenerator();

    // find the first index of cdf where it exceeds randomNumber
    // (findIndex() is in ES2015+)
    return cdf.findIndex(p => randomNumber < p);
}
```

The idea here is to turn the [list of probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) into something more like a [cumulative distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), where the element at index `i` represents how likely it is that the randomly chosen index will be less than or equal to `i`.  So, if your probabilities are `[4, 3, 2, 1]`, which normalizes to `[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]`, then the cumulative distribution is like `[0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0]`. Then all you have to find the first element of the cumulative distribution that exceeds some random number between 0 and 1.  Using the above `[0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0]` example, if the random number is between 0 and 0.4, the index will be `0`.  If it is between 0.4 and 0.7, then the index will be `1`.  If it is between 0.7 and 0.9, then the index will be `2`.  and if it is between 0.9 and 1.0, then the index will be `3`.  You can see how the probability of each index being produced is proportional to the value in the original `[4, 3, 2, 1]` list.

Let's try it on your example by running `randomIndex()` ten thousand times and comparing the frequency of hits for each index with the probability:

```
const probabilities = [50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
let hits = probabilities.map(x => 0);
const numAttempts = 10000;
for (let k = 0; k < numAttempts; k++) {
    hits[randomIndex(probabilities)]++;
}
for (let i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {
    console.log("" + i + ": prob=" + probabilities[i] + 
      ", freq=" + (100 * hits[i] / numAttempts).toFixed(1));
}

/*
Example of console.log output:
0: prob=50, frequency: 49.4
1: prob=10, freq=10.3
2: prob=10, freq=10.4
3: prob=10, freq=9.9
4: prob=10, freq=10.3
5: prob=2, freq=2.2
6: prob=2, freq=1.8
7: prob=2, freq=1.8
8: prob=2, freq=1.9
9: prob=2, freq=2.1
*/
```

Looks reasonable to me.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!